# как создать объект типа enum

Tags: java, enum, инициализация

```
public interface Product{
}

public enum ChocolateBars implements Product{
    MARS,SNICKERS TWIX;

    ChocolateBars(){
    }
}

public class stock{

    public void method(Product product){
        if(product instanceof ChocolateBars){
            Product pr = //продукт должен быть типа ChocolateBars
        }
    }
}
```

объект должен быть не MARS, SNICKERS или TWIX а именно ChocolateBars.

Comment: какая ошибка случилась?

Comment: дело не в ошибке, я не знаю что писать после оператора ровно

Comment: Непонятно, что Вы, собственно, хотите сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел ответ, ответ должен бы быть таким:

```
public class stock{

    public void method(Product product){
        if(product instanceof ChocolateBars){
            ChocolateBars chocolateBars = (ChocolateBars) product;
        }
    }
}
```

Спасибо за ответы и коментарии.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как должен писаться класс `enum` :

```
public enum ChocolateBars {
  MARS,SNICKERS TWIX;
}
```

Вот как долженсоздаваться `enum`-объект у тебя:

```
ChocolateBars bar = ChocolateBars.TWIX;
```

*Я до конца не понял твою программу, но думаю, что данный пример тебе поможет.*